# Google map API heatmap doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I write a demo not using ajax just use fixed data to draw using the same function, it works. But in here, I checked the data of mapData, map and heatmap, they looks the same with the simple demo, but no heatmap appears on my google map. I don't know how to deal with that,please help...

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
function buildMap(month, day) {
    var mapData = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'checkAccident.php',
        data: {
            "month": month,
            "day": day
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            result = eval(result);
            for (var o in result) {
                var lat = result[o].LATITUDE;
                var lng = result[o].LONGITUDE;
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                mapData.push(latLng);
            }

        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    //console.log(mapData);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ //draw
        data: mapData,
        dissipating: false,
        radius: 50,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Errors in console, do you see them?

Comment: there are no error in console. I can use console.log(heatmap) to check data of heatmap and it contains the data.

Comment: Ajax request is asynchronous. So you don't have `mapData` filled after `buildMap` function is over. Also I don't see how you call `buildMap`.

Comment: Sorry about the bad indent, it's my first time to ask questions. Creating heatmap is within the function buildMap, and it is called when select day and month. Actually mapData contains all data I needed.

Comment: What does commented `//console.log(mapData);` shows?

Comment: 0: _.E {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}
1: _.E {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}
something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving this code:

```
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ //draw
    data: mapData,
    dissipating: false,
    radius: 50,
    map: map
});
```

into the ajax success callback after you have populated the `mapData` array with the results from the ajax request.

The way your code is currently setup, you are passing in an empty array (`mapData`) to the `data` property of the `HeatmapLayer` options object. You need to set the data once you have received it from the ajax request (which does not finish instantaneously but some time in the future).

Comment: Could you please explain your down vote so I can improve my answer?